# Stop javascript execution on load in PHP file

Tags: javascript, php, cookies

Actuall I am trying to change the value of a cookie on page exit,

but the value of the cookie is changed during page load (rendering).

here is my code for deleting cookie

```
var show_close_alert = true;
    window.onbeforeunload = function() {
        if (show_close_alert) {
        ' <?php  $cookie = array(
        "name"   => "cookie",
        "value"  => "1",
        "expire" => time()-3600
        );
        $this->input->set_cookie($cookie);
        ?>'
     return 'window closing';
  }     
}
```

Code for adding cookie

```
$cookie = array(
      'name'   => 'cookie',
      'value'  => '1',
      'expire' => '29064'
    );
    $this->input->set_cookie($cookie);
```

How to fix this problem!

I have tried using php variable and changing its value at the end of .php file but that doesn't work

Comment: Please accept an answer or add your own answer and accept it. Doing that will prevent appearing this question as unanswered. @hass_

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because PHP parses and executes before the browser renders the page. You have to do an AJAX request to a script to remove the cookie.

Comment: but if the user closes the window before ajax request completes??

Comment: is there a way to change the cookie value (set in php) in javascript ?

Comment: you can catch the closing event of the browser and alert the user for the same.

Comment: Huh? The browser completes the request before the window gets unloaded and even if the window gets closed before the ajax request completes, the browser finishes the request. And you could unset the cookies via javascript too, if you didn't set the cookies httponly.

Comment: I have edited the question and added the setting method, can I use javascript for changing the cookie value, I have searched but haven't found a way to change value in javascript

Comment: Checkout: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie provides a very easy way to interact with cookies. Needs jQuery.